# Can we combine the usage of Vim Plugins: Ultisnips and youcompleteme, for using library function prototypes

Tags: vim, youcompleteme, ultisnips

I am using Ultisnips and youcompleteme plugins. In my C++ project, I have set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON) that gives me intellisense completion based on the context.

I want to use the "completion" results provided by youcompleteme, and use it as a snippet to jump to different required fields.

For example(opencv c++):

```
cv::Mat image = cv::imread(argv[1],1);
cv::namedWind
```

So, when I select any of the provided completion option, the whole function prototype should be inserted and I should be able to jump through the parameters(snippet fields) to enter the values.

In general, can we do this for any third party libraries.

Reference Image:  [ycmCompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vTp4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

https://github.com/tenfyzhong/CompleteParameter.vim

But, not finding an option to change the trigger(by default set to '(') key.